# Exponential Functions build Basis for Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, exponential-function, change-of-basis

Let $V$ be a subspace of the $R$-Vectorspace of all differentiable functions defined by $V := span\{(t-34)e^t, (6t+1)e^t + e^{2t}, e^{2t}, e^t\}$.

I do not know how to start with finding a basis for vector space $V$. Intuitively I would check if the functions in the $span$ are linearly independent. Yet, I don't know what to do with the exponentials as I have never faced such an exercise before.

Could you please give me a hint?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your first idea is good, just start with a family of one vector like ${e^t}$ and progressively add linearly independent vectors from the span . For example it should not be difficult to show that ${e^t}$ and ${e^{2t}}$ are independent by just applying the definition of linear independency and evaluating at some values of $t$.

Comment: @Lelouch Will do that! I guess I have to use differentiation in order to make a system of linear equations that allows me to get the coefficients? Thank you so much.

Comment: I dont think you need to differentiate. The key is to understand that linear independency of $e^t$ and $e^{2t}$ as FUNCTIONS is linked to the existence of $\alpha, \beta$ INDEPENDENT OF $t$ such as $\alpha e^t + \beta e^{2t}=0 \forall t$ (FOR ALL t is important). If only $\alpha=\beta=0$ works then you have independent functions. For example you can evaluate the equality for $t=0$ and $t=1$ you get two equations to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I already got that $e^t$ and $e^{2t}$ are independent. If I also add $(t-34)e^t$, would I then need to evaluate at 3 values of $t$? Sorry for my nooby questions but I really struggle to get these concepts

Comment: You can do what you want, just collect information (i.e apply for the values of $t$ you want) to find the values of the coefficients. Here as an intuition, you have a $te^t$ term that is clearly not linear in any combination of $e^t$ and $e^{2t}$ so you will expect this term not to be in span{$e^t$,$e^{2t}$}. Can you find non-zeros $\alpha$, $\beta$ such as $te^t = \alpha e^t + \beta e^{2t}$ ? If not then the family spanned by the three vectors is an independent family.

Comment: Shouldn't I check $(t-34)e^t = ae^t + be^{2t}$ to check if these three are independent? If yes, I got that they are dependent because it holds for $a = -37, b=3, t=0$ (?).

Comment: You have to check that, yes. The same value of $a$ and $b$ is supposed to work for EVERY $t$, not only one $t$. I gave you a detailed answer (maybe with some typo) so that you can get an idea of what a complete redaction would look like. But continue working on your own to understand the things.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the spanning family can generate the entire space, but there might be redundant information inside so we will try to extract a basis from the spanning family, which might contains less than $4$ vectors.

I'll go in the very details fist to show what a complete and "naive" write-up might be and then I'll give a more "high level" answer that involves much less computations.

---

Let's start with the simplest family containing only one vector ($e^t$), well $e^t$ is obviously not the null function and thus this family is  linearly independent .

Then we will add a second vector, for example the other simplest one $e^{2t}$. If $e^{2t}$ is NOT proportional to $e^t$, then the family ($e^t,e^{2t}$) will still be linearly independent. Let $\alpha$ such as $\forall t$, $e^t = \alpha e^{2t}$. We can evaluate at $t=1$ and we get $e=\alpha e^2$ so $\alpha=e^{-1}$. We can also evaluate at $t=2$ and we get $e^2=\alpha e^4$, which means that $\alpha = e^{-2}$. Since $e^{-1} \neq e^{-2}$, we obtain a contradiction and $\alpha$ does not exist and thefore $e^{2t}$ is not proportional to $e^t$.
At this point we know that the family ($e^t, e^{2t}$) is linearly independent.

Now lets try to add a third vector $(t-34)e^t$. We will apply the same technique, i.e we will see if this vector is inside the vector space spanned by the two previous vectors. Let $\alpha, \beta$ so that $\forall t$, $(t-34)e^t= \alpha e^t + \beta e^{2t}$. By setting $\alpha' = \alpha + 34$, we obtain a simplified equation  $te^t= \alpha' e^t + \beta e^{2t}$. By evaluating at $t=0$ we obtain $0=\alpha' + \beta$ and thus $\alpha' = - \beta$. By evaluating at $t=1$, we get $e=-\beta e+\beta e^2$ i.e $\beta = \frac{1}{e-1}$. However if we evaluate at $t=2$, we get $2e^2 = -\beta e^2 + \beta e^4$, leading to $\beta=\frac{2}{e^2-1}$. Again since $\frac{1}{e-1} \neq \frac{2}{e^2-1}$ we conclude that such $\alpha, \beta$ do not exist. $(e^t, e^{2t}, (t-34)e^t)$ is a linearly independent family.

What about the fourth vector $(6t+1)e^t+e^{2t}$ ? Well we do not need any computation this time. This term is a linear combination of $te^t, e^{2t}$ and $e^t$ which are already in $(e^t, e^{2t}, (t-34)e^t)$ and therefore the complete family is linearly dependent this time.

Conclusion : $(e^t, e^{2t}, (t-34)e^t)$ is a possible basis.

---

Nevertheless, if you take a step back, you can see that three elementary functions appear in these four vectors: $e^t, e^{2t}$ and $te^t$ . You can get all the 4 vectors as a linear combination of these three elementary functions. By postulating from the start that the family $(e^t, e^{2t},te^t)$ is a basis, we could avoid a lot of calculations. To me this appears at the most natural basis.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed walk through! Helped a ton :)

Comment: Please feel free to check the intermediary results/computations I wrote this pretty quickly but the reasoning should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly will need $e^t$ and $e^{2t}$.  You will also need $te^t$.  $\{e^t, e^{2t}, te^t\}$ is a basis.

Comment: Thought about this yes, yet I did not know how to get there.

Comment: If we can produce  $(t−34)e^t$,$(6t+1)e^t+e^{2t}$,$e^{2t}$, and $e^t$ then  can produce anything in their span.